# Adt repository down?

Tags: android, eclipse

Google's repository for the ADT plugin for eclipse seems to be throwing a 404 error.https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ Is there any alternate way of installing the plugin?

Comment: Did you try using the unsecure address?  Also, I don't know if this belongs here. Not really a programming question, and is answered by the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-12.0.0.zip

Here is the manual link to download it. in the install new software area choose archive instead of add site